# How to get all order ID which not paid in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to get all order id numbers for selected customer which not paid till now, my data show as following:

[image]

What I want is Write a SELECT statement that answers this question:

```
select orderID 
from order 
where customer id = @custID 
and Total cashmovementValue 
        for current order id 
    is less than total (sold quantity * salePrice ) 
        for current order id
```

How to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compare the sum of each order line with the sum of each payment per order. [GROUP BY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms177673%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and a few sub-queries is what you need to get the job done.

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT
    O.OrderID
FROM [Order] O
INNER JOIN (
   -- Add up cost per order
   SELECT 
       OrderID,
       SUM(SoldQuantity * P.SalePrice) AS Total
   FROM OrderLine
   INNER JOIN Product P ON P.ProductID = OrderLine.ProductID     
   GROUP BY OrderID
) OL ON OL.OrderID = O.OrderID
LEFT JOIN (
    -- Add up total amount paid per order
    SELECT
        OrderID,
        SUM(CashMovementValue) AS Total
    FROM CashMovement
    GROUP BY OrderID
) C ON C.OrderID = O.OrderID
WHERE
    O.CustomerID = @custID
    AND ( C.OrderID IS NULL OR C.Total < OL.Total )
```

**EDIT**

I've just noticed you're not storing the sale price on each order line. I've updated my answer accordingly, but this is a very bad idea. What will happen to your old orders if the price of an item changes? It is okay (and actually best practice) to denormalise the data by storing the price at the time of sale on each order line.